# How to access a value of a dynamic key in memsql

Tags: sql, singlestore

I have a MemSQL database with a table:

MyTable

| primaryId | configuration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { [keyID]: { status: "open" } } |
| 2 | { [keyID]: { status: "closed" } } |

The key `keyID` is a dynamic key e.g uuid that gets randomly generated whenever a new item is inserted into the table.

Is there a way to access the status value inside the configuration column in MemSQL. e.g:

```
SELECT primaryId, status
FROM MyTable
WHERE configuration::$[keyID]::$status IN ("open", "closed")
```

provided that I don't know what value the `[keyID]` might resolve to?

Any help is appreaciated, thanks.

Comment: Not sure why the table doesn't show correctly, it showed perfectly fine in my preview during editing phase.